# Drools windowed event processing

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion

I can not understand the behavior of drools windows that i need for correlation of events, i mean i want to calculate the total amount of Objects with amount property inserting in engine over last 10 secs.

Here is my rule pattern:

```
     Number( intValue >1000) from accumulate(Test( $p:price ) over window:time( 10s ),sum( $p ) )
```

It gives a compilation error:

```
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Example 1']
com/retailerdev/rules/Rule_Example_1.java (15:660) : $p cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Please help .Thanks in advance

Comment: This works fine in 5.5.0 and 5.3.0. I suspect that you have omitted some relevant detail. Please post full code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually i was using $p in when condition and it does not have scope there thats why  $p cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: hey laune , buddy can you help me about drools? may be in some chat or e-mail i would be very thankful. PLEASE

Comment: Always post code that reproduces the problem, not what you *think* that causes it. And there's another recent post on Drools from you, and we haven't seen a reaction from you on that one. As for help: what's wrong with stackoverflow? And there's the Drools user list...